# Undefined model by using Join Query in Laravel

Tags: api, join, laravel-5, model, resources

I am indexing apples with their specified properties (such as color) using API Laravel. I use join to retrieve apples which are related to a specified brand. but it does not retrieve apples with their own specified properties which are defined in another DB and models.

```
public function index(Brand $brand)
    {
       $apples = Apple::join('brands', 'brand_id', 'brands.id')->where('brand_id', $brand->id)->get();    
       return returnSuccessfulResponse(
              trans('api.response.successful.index'),
              Resource::collection($apples)
           ); 
    }
```

Apple model:

```
public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
public function appleProperties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AppleProperty::class);
    }
```

Resource:

```
return [
           'id' => $this->brand->id,
           'name' => $this->brand->name,
           'apple-properties' => $this->appleProperties,
       ];
```

Route:

```
Route::apiResource('brands/{brand}/apples', 'AppleController');
```

It is not retrieving `appleProperties`. I do not understand that reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use join() method in your queries, it is recommended to use select() as well, so that is no longer ambiguous which table you referenced to. In your code, the query may be something like this:

```
$apples = Apple::join('brands', 'brand_id', 'brands.id')->select('apples.*')->where('brand_id', $brand->id)->get();
```